# How can I define priors in rstanarm using R

Tags: r, function, bayesian, stan, mlogit

I am trying to generate a logit bayesian regression model using the library `rstanarm`.

This is a simplified version of the code (including data generation) that works

```
#Data Generation
set.seed(1) 
tamanioMuestraSi=103
tamanioMuestraNo=127

etiquetaSi <- rep(1, times = tamanioMuestraSi)
etiquetaNo <- rep(0, times = tamanioMuestraNo)

cantidadCoches<- 0:5
probabilidadesCochesSi <- c(0.2, 0.25, 0.25, 0.2, 0.06, 0.04)
probabilidadesCochesNo <- c(0.4, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1, 0.08, 0.02)



  cochesSi <- sample(cantidadCoches, size = tamanioMuestraSi, replace = TRUE, prob = probabilidadesCochesSi)
  cochesNo <- sample(cantidadCoches, size = tamanioMuestraNo, replace = TRUE, prob = probabilidadesCochesNo)


mediaSueldoSi<- 2000
stdSueldoSi <- 150

mediaSueldoNo<- 1200
stdSueldoNo <- 110

sueldoSi <- rnorm(n = tamanioMuestraSi, mean = mediaSueldoSi, sd = stdSueldoSi)
sueldoNo <- rnorm(n = tamanioMuestraNo, mean = mediaSueldoNo, sd = stdSueldoNo)

estadoHospital<- 0:1
probabilidadesEstadoHospitalSi <- c(0.05, 0.95)
probabilidadesEstadoHospitalNo <- c(0.1, 0.9)


  hospSi <- sample(estadoHospital, size = tamanioMuestraSi, replace = TRUE, prob = probabilidadesEstadoHospitalSi)
  hospNo <- sample(estadoHospital, size = tamanioMuestraNo, replace = TRUE, prob = probabilidadesEstadoHospitalNo)
  

datosSi<- data.frame(Etiqueta = etiquetaSi, Coche = cochesSi,
                     Sueldo=sueldoSi, Hospitalizado = hospSi)

datosNo<- data.frame(Etiqueta = etiquetaNo, Coche = cochesNo, 
                     Sueldo=sueldoNo, Hospitalizado = hospNo)

datosCreditoOrdenados <- rbind(datosSi, datosNo)

datosCreditoRandomizando <- sample(nrow(datosCreditoOrdenados))
datosCredito <- datosCreditoOrdenados[datosCreditoRandomizando , ]

############## Working Model Starts Here #########################
library(bayesplot)
library(rstanarm) 
library(ggplot2)
library(modelsummary)
library(knitr)


fit <- stan_glm(Etiqueta ~ ., family = binomial(link = "logit"),
                data = datosCredito, verbose = F, refresh = 0)

efectos_fijos<-get_estimates(fit)
kable(efectos_fijos, booltabs=T, digits=3,
      caption="Efectos fijos del modelo Consumo de gasolina")

posterior <- as.matrix(fit)
plot_title <- ggtitle("Posterior Coche",
                      "Con la mediana y un intervalo de confianza del 80%")
mcmc_areas(posterior,
           pars = c("Coche"),
           prob = 0.8) + plot_title
```

I want to provide suitable priors to the functions, so I change the code to instead bel

```
# Define priors for binary variables
prior_hospitalizado <- prior(bernoulli(0.5), "Hospitalizado")

# Define priors for count variables
prior_coche <- prior(poisson(2), "Coche")

# Define priors for continuous variables
prior_sueldo <- prior(normal(0, 1000), "Sueldo")


# Combine all the priors
all_priors <- prior_hospitalizado +
              prior_coche +
              prior_sueldo 

# Fit the model with the updated priors
fit <- stan_glm(Etiqueta ~ ., family = binomial(link = "logit"),
                prior = all_priors,
                data = datosCredito, verbose = F, refresh = 0)
```

Then, I am gettin an error `Error in prior(bernoulli(0.5), "Hospitalizado") :  could not find function "prior"`  Can someone help me to propperly program said priors. There is an example [here](https://mc-stan.org/rstanarm/reference/priors.html), but it does just use one prior. This [other example](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rstanarm/vignettes/priors.html) confuses me further.

Any guidance is appreciated.